# Upload not working with PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload

> Error  Warning: stripos(): needle is not a string or an integer in `C:\wamp\www\projeodevim\dosyayukle.php on line 24`

```
$say=0;
include('config.php');


$dosyasayisi=count($_FILES['dosya']['name']);

$dosyaizinadmin=mysql_query("select dosyaizin from admin");
$izinsonuc=mysql_fetch_array($dosyaizinadmin);
$sorgu=mysql_query("select * from dosyaturleri where dosyakategori='$izinsonuc[0]'");

while($dosyaturlerim=mysql_fetch_array($sorgu)){
    //storing all allowed extensions:
    $allowed[] = $dosyaturlerim['dosyatur'];
                        }
    for($i=0;$i<$dosyasayisi;$i++){
        echo $dosyaturlerim['dosyatur'];

        //getting file extension
        $filename = $_FILES['dosya']['name'][$i];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(stripos($ext ,$allowed)!==FALSE){
            echo "image/".$ext;
            echo 'ekleme yapıldı';

        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here and you have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries using placeholder values. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices when interfacing with databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have `$allowed[]` as an array, not as a string. For `stripos()` you should pass 2 strings.

You can use in_array() to check.

```
                $dosyasayisi=count($_FILES['dosya']['name']);

                $dosyaizinadmin=mysql_query("select dosyaizin from admin");
                $izinsonuc=mysql_fetch_array($dosyaizinadmin);
                $sorgu=mysql_query("select * from dosyaturleri where dosyakategori='$izinsonuc[0]'");

                while($dosyaturlerim=mysql_fetch_array($sorgu))
                        {
                        //storing all allowed extensions:
                $allowed[] = $dosyaturlerim['dosyatur'];
                        }
                for($i=0;$i<$dosyasayisi;$i++)
{
                echo $dosyaturlerim['dosyatur'];

                    //getting file extension
                $filename = $_FILES['dosya']['name'][$i];
                $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(in_array($ext, $allowed)){
                        echo "image/".$ext;
                        echo 'ekleme yapıldı';

                        }

    }
```

Comment: What can I make for the problem ?

Comment: i added (after the last if) else{ echo 'File extension error';} and give the message... I selected .jpg and This extension added in database ?

Comment: @OnePage I'm sorry, I just realized that I was meaning to use in_array there and instead put stripos -_- and also in this answer there's a little bit of correction.